# How can I perform a slow shutdown on the power supply of an RTC after turning off the circuit?

Tags: power-supply, rtc

I have designed a circuit that includes an RTC, the model is RV-3032-C7. We were able to configure it and the device performs its function, but I have a big problem. Occasionally, when I turn off and then turn on the circuit again, I notice that the RTC loses time (this only happens a few times, once or twice a month), and it's a headache because we don't know why it's happening. We think that the power supply may not be stable enough, so I wanted to ask two things:

- Does anyone with experience in circuits with RTCs know why this problem occurs?
- How can I maintain the power supply voltage of the circuit long enough for the RTC to switch its power source input to the battery?

---

Here I add the electrical diagram that I designed:
[image]

Comment: Diode + capacitor?

Comment: Is it possible that the rest of your system is performing an I2C transaction on the RTC I2C bus as it loses VDD, which causes the transaction to get corrupted?

Comment: Your design is generally good. 4.7k On I2C lines (SCL/SDA) is ok if you keep your I2C bus short.  I would change R25 to 10k to match datasheet and reduce current draw.  R27 1K value seems aggressive.  What was the goal there?

Comment: The problem is, why it loses time can't be guessed from those schematics. Maybe your MCU accidentally overwrites the time. For example what happens if MCU loses power during when there is an ongoing transaction? Will MCU drain the backup battery via INT pin?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for time loss on an RTC is a negative voltage spike on any of the inputs.  This can cause the RTC to reset.  Limits from manual:
VDD -0.3V to 6V, Input and Output pins -0.3V to VSS+0.3V.